# Usefulness of a Hermitian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-computation, hermitian-matrices

A Hermitian Matrix is defined as a self-adjoint matrix (so the complex conjugate transpose of M is equal to M).
But the usefulness of Hermitian Matrices seems to be that they necessarily have orthogonal eigenvectors that span the space and that all eigenvalues are real.

If I tell you I have a matrix whose eigenvectors are orthogonal, span the space, and whose eigenvalues are all real, does this necessarily mean I have a Hermitian matrix? If not, is there a general name for such a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

If $M = UDU^*$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is a real diagonal matrix, we have
$$M^* = (UDU^*)^* = (U^*)^*D^*U^* = UDU^* = M,$$ so $M$ is self-adjoint.